# Velocity Template for XML

Tags: velocity

Is it necessary to use Velocity Template to create XML Template???

Comment: What do you mean by XML template?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can template XML using Velocity but there are other methods that can be used such as XSLT

Answer (score 0):

you can try **quick-templates** to get XML/JSON templating capability

offers more capabilities than apache velocity

```
    IEngine templateEngine=EngineFactory.getInstance().getEngine(EngineType.TEMPLATES);

    templateEngine.initialize("/com/tester/template-rules-config.xml");

    long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

    EngineResponse response=templateEngine.execute(context);
```

[Quick-Templates](https://github.com/rajeshputta1983/quick-templates)